# Angular MouseEvent on :after element gives wrong value for event.toElement.clientWidth

Tags: javascript, css, angular

I have a audio player element i am designing in Angular that mimics the soundcloud player that sits at the bottom of the soundcloud page.

It has an orange line (**player-progress-current**) which depicts the elements of the track that have already been played. It also has an orange circle depicting the current position of the track.

When I click anywhere on the **'player-progress-container'** div (see below) it gives the current position, the **event.layerX** position, and the **event.toElement.clientWidth** which is the width of it's parent the **player-progress-container**. I use this to then change the position of the audio player.

However when I click on the circle element I have representing the current position of the track, which is the **player-progress-current:after** element below it calculates the **event.layerX** position correctly, but the **event.toElement.clientWidth** now seems to be given as the width of the player-progress-current, instead of it's parent.

Does anybody know why it does this, and how to work around it? I've included all the relevant CSS, HTML, and Angular stuff below

```
changePosition(event: MouseEvent) {
    console.log("event.layerX  = " + event.layerX);
    console.log("event.clientWidth = " + event.toElement.clientWidth);
}
```

The HTML looks like this:

```
<div class="player-progress-container" (click)="changePosition($event)">
    <div class="player-progress-background"></div>
    <div class="player-progress-current"
        [style.width.%]="(position * 100)/length"></div>
</div>
```

The CSS looks like this:

```
.player-progress-container {
  width: 400px;
  flex-grow: 1;
  padding: 10px 0px 2px 0px;
  margin: 0px 10px 0 10px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.player-progress-background {
  width: 100%;
  height: 1px;
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.player-progress-current {
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
  height: 1px;
  background: red;
  bottom: 1px;
}

.player-progress-current:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  right:-3px; top: -3.5px;
  border: 1px solid #f50;
  border-radius: 55%;
  height: 8px;
  width: 8px;
  background-color: #f50;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Comment: In addition to @ConnorsFan answer below, I would also add a question about this:  
`[style.width.%]="(position * 100)/length"` Why not do that calculation in a function in your component passing in values like he said below?

Comment: @jmb.mage why would it be better to do it in a function than in the html?

Comment: @tom-obrien It's a coding practice choice. Reason #1: scope, having JS variables inside an HTML file makes it difficult to determine what scope they are in. Keeping JS in the JS file just keeps scope clean and easy.  Reason 2: if the JS code grows or changes, it's nicer to have in a component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make sure that you always get the width of the container, you can pass that element as an argument to `changePosition`, with the help of a [template reference variable](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#template-reference-variables--var-):

```
<div #container class="player-progress-container" (click)="changePosition($event, container)">
  ...
</div>
```

```
changePosition(event: MouseEvent, container: HTMLElement) {
  console.log("event.layerX  = " + event.layerX);
  console.log("clientWidth = " + container.clientWidth);
}
```

See [**this stackblitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wesuxu) for a demo.

---

As an alternative, you could pass `layerX` and `clientWidth` directly to `changePosition`:

```
<div #container (click)="changePosition($event.layerX, container.clientWidth)" ...>
  ...
</div>
```

```
changePosition(layerX: number, clientWidth: number) {
  console.log("layerX  = " + layerX);
  console.log("clientWidth = " + clientWidth);
}
```

See [**this stackblitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-slj8sx) for a demo.